# How can I RANK from AVG sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble retrieving the rankings from a single line that has some uuid from that:

```sql
SELECT uuid , AVG(nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 as Average
from elo_ranked group by uuid
order by AVG(nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 desc
limit 3
```

I specify that the above function works and has the expected result.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT uuid, AVG(nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 as Average ,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 DESC) as ranking
FROM elo_ranked 
GROUP BY uuid
ORDER BY AVG(nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 desc 
LIMIT 3;
```

EDIT:

To rank a specific user, use a subquery:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT uuid, AVG(nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 as Average ,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 DESC) as ranking
      FROM elo_ranked 
      GROUP BY uuid
     ) u
WHERE uuid = ?;
```

Also, I'm not sure if you need the aggregation.  That would only be needed if a user had multiple rows in the `elo_ranked` table.  If not needed, then you should use:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT uuid, (nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 as Average ,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (nodebuff+debuff+archer+builduhc+uhc+gapple)/6 DESC) as ranking
      FROM elo_ranked 
     ) u
WHERE uuid = ?;
```

The `GROUP BY` has a lot of overhead, so this should be faster (unless MySQL has sophisticated optimizations to avoid the aggregation when grouping by a primary key).

Comment: Sort of yes, except I'd like to get the rank of a specific uuid.

Comment: @waikickappdev . . . This returns the ranks of all the UUIDs returned by your query.  That seems to address the question that you asked:  "the rankings from . . some uuid from"

Comment: Yes, I miswrote it. But I do want to get the rank of a specific uuid in the result of your request.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it seems there's still a problem because it's sending me back an error... `Unknown column '2753a8a7-fe71-4897-be61-d767d768a2b9' in 'where clause'`